# Z-Index for Fixed Positioning ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So I've been working on a webpage and I'm trying to have some text be fixed in the center of the screen, but once they scroll down the text will go under the other divs and be un-seen. Here is my code:

```
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="bg__1">
        <div class="Absolute-Center">
        <span style="font-size: 50px; color: aqua">in short.</span><br />
        LIVE LIFE AT YOUR OWN PACE.</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ($) {
                var h1Animation = 'animated bounceIn';
                $('p').addClass(h1Animation);
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="bg__2" ></div>
    <div class="bg__3"></div>
    <div class="bg__4"></div>
</div>
```

I want the `<div class="Absolute-Center">` to have its contents render under all the following divs (bg__2, bg__3, bg__4).
CSS Code:

```
[class*="bg__"] {
    height: 60vh;
    /* fix background */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* center it */
    background-position: center center;
    /* Scale it nicely to the element */
    background-size: cover;
    /* just make it look a bit better ;) */
    &:nth-child(2n) {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em #111;
    }
}

.Absolute-Center {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-right: -150px;
}
```

I have tried adding z-index properties to "bg__1" and to "Absolute-Center", both attempts failed.

Comment: I don't see any `z-index` property in your code; have you tried adding it?

Comment: I just edited question. I have tried lowering the z-index in "bg__1" and "Absolute-Center" as well as raising the z-index for the other divs. None of it has worked.

Comment: Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Try to use a negative `z-index` on `.Absolute-Center` like so `z-index: -1`.

Comment: Not an answer I'd prefer `.parallax > div {}` over `[class*="bg__"] {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `z-index: -1` to `.Absolute-Center`. This will change the stack level of the generated box ( `.Absolute-Center` ). [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index) you can find more information on the `z-index` property and the stack order.

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  var h1Animation = 'animated bounceIn';
  $('p').addClass(h1Animation);
});
```

```css
[class*="bg__"] {
  height: 60vh;
  /* fix background */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* center it */
  background-position: center center;
  /* Scale it nicely to the element */
  background-size: cover;
  /* just make it look a bit better ;) */
}

[class*="bg__"]:nth-child(2n) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em #111;
}

.bg__2 {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1200x500');
}
.bg__4 {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1200x500');
}


.Absolute-Center {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-right: -150px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="bg__1">
    <div class="Absolute-Center">
      <span style="font-size: 50px; color: aqua">in short.</span><br />
      LIVE LIFE AT YOUR OWN PACE.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg__2"></div>
  <div class="bg__3"></div>
  <div class="bg__4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use z-index, you have to have absolute or relative positioning on the element you want to use a z-index on.  So, I think you should be able to add the following to your CSS to get what you need:

```
.bg__2, .bg__3, .bg__4{position:relative; z-index:2}
.bg__1{z-index:1;}
```

Comment: This method does work, however it causes A LOT of frame lag when scrolling. Im not sure if the relative position conflicts with the fixed background position or ...?